# Remove named imports in Typescript output

Tags: node.js, typescript, module

In my tsconfig.json

```
"target": "esnext"
"module": "esnext"
```

In my package.json

```
"type": "module"
```

My source files are .mts, my output is .mjs. This is the error I'm getting.

```
import { model, Schema } from 'mongoose';
            ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'Schema' not found. The requested module 'mongoose' is a 
CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using

import pkg from 'mongoose';
const { model, Schema } = pkg;
```

Now I understand you can't use named imports from commonjs module generally. But working with Typescript I thought there'd be a way to write named imports in my source files, and have the compiled output remove them. The problem is I don't know how.

I tried to compile my code to commonjs but I run into this problem

```
exports is not defined in es module scope
```

I suspect because my output is .mjs. I definitely don't want to switch all my project to .ts.

So is there a way to have my output not use named imports without me doing something annoying like this in my source code?

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
const someSchema = new mongoose.Schema(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, because `mongoose` is still a CommonJS module, you can only import names which are set on `module.exports` (and there aren't any other than the `mongoose` module itself, which is the default export). [The documentation](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose#importing) makes this clear.

If you don't want to use a form of dot or bracket property access notation when using the properties of `mongoose`, then you can:

- destructure the destructurable ones like this:

  ```ts
  import mongoose from 'mongoose';
  const {Schema} = mongoose;
  console.log(new Schema());
  ```
- [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) ones that might depend on their `this` value being `mongoose`:

  ```ts
  import mongoose from 'mongoose';
  const Schema = mongoose.Schema.bind(mongoose);
  console.log(new Schema());
  ```

> Note, you'll also need to set these TSConfig options: `compilerOptions.allowSyntheticDefaultImports` to `true`, and `compilerOptions.moduleResolution` to `"node"`.

Comment: Well, ok, I understand I can't in the output, just thought there was a way to write it like that in my source and then have typescript transform to dot notation so I can run it without errors, but also not bother with it while writing typescript code.

Comment: On a side note, how dumb would it be to have a folder like "../imports/mongoose" and import everything from mongoose there and export what I need, and then use bracket notation in my files from that file instead. (Yes I am that obsessed with the bracket notation)

Comment: @Megid There's nothing wrong at all with importing an object like mongoose and then re-exporting specific properties by name for use in other modules. That's a great idea if you're importing them in multiple modules.